# Django stay signed for two weeks or till browser is closed

Tags: django

I have a `stay signed` field in login form in my app and I want to allow user to decide whether he wants to stay signed for 2 weeks or being logged out when the browser closes.

This is part of the code I wrote and am using, and it is working. I simply check if user checked to stay signed and when he didn't I set expire time of session to 0. I've looked into source of django `SessionBase` and it seems that 0 equals session expire on browser close.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if not form.cleaned_data['stay_signed']:
        self.request.session.set_expiry(0)
    login(self.request, form.get_user())
    redirect_url = self.request.GET.get(REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, None)
    if redirect_url:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I wonder if this is a good and safe solution.

Answer (score 0):

also you can do that:

```
    from django.conf import settings

    if form_data.cleaned_data['stay_signed'] == True:
       settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
    else:
       settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

    login(request, user_obj)
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is better?